# Disable snapping for knife tool cut?

Tags: knife-tool

If I use the knife tool, and I use it near edges, the mouse will snap to them and it wont allow to me make lines close to it unless I zoom in very close.
How can I disable snapping for the knife tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while using the knife tool to disable snapping. Look in the 3D view header and you will see the knife tool options and keys to press. The image below is a screen shot of the 3D view header during the use of the knife tool.
<sub>click for full size</sub>
[image: knife tool options]